# php while loop with $i++

Tags: php, while-loop

What I want to do is have a radio button inside a while loop and the name of the radio to be increased by 1 every time the loop is ran.
Right now the code is not working because it is not incrementally increasing. Any suggestions would be great.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY time ASC");
echo '<table> <th> A </th> <th> time </th> <th> B </th>'; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $i= 1;
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="';echo $i++; echo'" /> '; echo $row['a'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['time'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="';echo $i++; echo '" />'; echo $row['b'];
    echo '</td> </tr> ';
}


echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: You're setting `$i` to 1 inside your while loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're resetting your counter each time.

```
$i = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // Your code

    $i++;
}
```

.. and replace `echo $i++;` with `echo $i;`.

Answer (score 1):

just move the `$i= 1;` outside the loop

like this for instance:

```
...
$i= 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ...
    echo '<input type="radio" name="';echo $i; echo'" /> '; echo $row['a'];
    ...
    ...
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your logic is not valid:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$i++;
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="';echo $i; echo'" /> '; echo $row['a'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row['time'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="';echo $i; echo '" />'; echo $row['b'];
echo '</td> </tr> ';
}
```

every time you type `$i++` PHP will increment it.

Answer (score 0):

Hehe.. ;))

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY time ASC");

echo "<table>\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "    <th> A </th>\n";
echo "    <th> time </th>\n";
echo "    <th> B </th>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";

$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "  <tr>\n"
    echo '    <td><input type="radio" name="' . $i . '" />' . $row['a'] . "</td>\n";
    echo '    <td>' . $row['time'] . "</td>\n";
    echo '    <td><input type="radio" name="' . $i . '" />' . $row['b'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "  </tr>\n";
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>\n";
```

I didn't check your code including the SQL query if it's right, yet do the rest to fix this code if there's an error or if the format wasn't right!