# Iteration inside while loop is not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying iteration in WordPress while loop with $i. But it's printing 1 for the first item and 3 for the remaining items.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while($posts->have_posts()){
        $i++;
        $posts->the_post();

        $html .= '<div class="th-block ' . $i . '">';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    echo $html;
 ?>
```

But it's printing like this

```
<div class="th-block 1"></div>
<div class="th-block 3"></div>
<div class="th-block 3"></div>
<div class="th-block 3"></div>
....
```

Do I need to fix a limit within the loop? I searched on stackoverflow but not found any solution for this.

Comment: Print $i on each loop and see what it gives.  Does `$posts->have_posts()` or `$posts->the_post();` modify $i in any way?

Comment: I have checked with your script, it is working fine. script return something like below.<div class="th-block 1"></div>
<div class="th-block 2"></div>
<div class="th-block 3"></div>
<div class="th-block 4"></div>

Answer (score -3, accepted):

change name of "i" variable . 
wordpress some time use global variable with this name.

just change it to something like iiiii jjjjj

Answer (score 0):

It seems a very minor issue, try below code this will work for you.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while($posts->have_posts()){
        $posts->the_post();

        $html .= '<div class="th-block ' . $i . '">';
        $html .= '</div>';

        $i++;
    }
    echo $html;
 ?>
```

I have not tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello it is very simple

```
 <?php
        $i = 0;
        while($posts->have_posts()){
            $posts->the_post();

            $html .= '<div class="th-block ' . $i . '">';
            $html .= '</div>';

            $i++;
        }
        echo $html;
     ?>
```

You have to just add $i++ after your HTML content but now your HTML is displayed like this

```
<div class="th-block 0"></div>
<div class="th-block 1"></div>
<div class="th-block 2"></div>
<div class="th-block 3"></div>
```

if you want to start from one just user $i = 1 instead of zero

Answer (score 0):

Refer : [php while loop with $i++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748840/php-while-loop-with-i)

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while($posts->have_posts()){
        $posts->the_post();

        $html .= '<div class="th-block ' . <?php echo $i; ?> . '">';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo $html;
 ?>
```