# How to select the element number 10 and 25 of my loop, to remove <a></a>?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

i need your help.
How can i remove the  tag of the numbers 10 and 25 in my loop?
Here is the code below, thank you in advance.

```
function myFunction() {
        $markup = '';
        
        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'partner',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'partner_type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'national'
                )
            )
        );
        
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        if ($loop->found_posts > 0) {
            $markup .= '<div class="container ap-national-partners">';
            $markup .= '<div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">';
            
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $imageId = get_field("logo");
            
                if ($imageId) {
                    $imageDetails = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageId, 'full');
                    
                    if ($imageDetails !== false) {
                        $markup .= '<div class="col-2 mt-5">';
                        $markup .= '<a href="' . get_field("url") . '" target="_blank">';
                        $markup .= '<img src="' . $imageDetails[0] . '" class="img-fluid" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" width="' . $imageDetails[1] . '" height="' . $imageDetails[2] . '" />';
                        $markup .= '</a>';
                    }
                }
                
                $markup .= '</a>';
                $markup .= '</div>';
            endwhile;
            
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
            $markup .= '</div>';
            $markup .= '</div>';
        }
        
        return $markup;
    }
```

I tried to add this code below inside the loop, but it doesn t work.

```
if ($imageDetails == 25) {
     $markup .= '<div class="col-2 mt-5">';
     $markup .= '<img src="' . $imageDetails[0] . '" class="img-fluid" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" width="' . $imageDetails[1] . '" height="' . $imageDetails[2] . '" />';
     $markup .= '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Put a counter outside the loop, increment inside the loop. Compare inside the loop for 10 or 25.

Comment: Hi Markus Zeller, thank you for your quick answer.
Do you think you can provide the code?

Comment: Related: [Iteration inside while loop is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59100334/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Put a counter outside the loop, increment inside the loop. Compare inside the loop for 10 or 25.

```
function myFunction() {
    $markup = '';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'partner',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'partner_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'national'
            )
        )
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($loop->found_posts > 0) {
        $markup .= '<div class="container ap-national-partners">';
        $markup .= '<div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">';

        $articleCounter = 1;
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $imageId = get_field("logo");

            if ($imageId) {
                $imageDetails = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageId, 'full');

                if ($imageDetails !== false) {
                    $imageMarkUp = '<img src="' . $imageDetails[0] . '" class="img-fluid" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" width="' . $imageDetails[1] . '" height="' . $imageDetails[2] . '" />';
                    $markup .= '<div class="col-2 mt-5">';
                    if (in_array($articleCounter, [10, 25], true)) {
                        $markup .= $imageMarkUp;
                    } else {
                        $markup .= '<a href="' . get_field("url") . '" target="_blank">';
                        $markup .= $imageMarkUp;
                        $markup .= '</a>';
                    }
                    $markup .= '</div>';
                }
            }

            $articleCounter++;
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        $markup .= '</div>';
        $markup .= '</div>';
    }

    return $markup;
}
```